# php's set_time_limit(0) hangs and throws HTTP 500

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

This simple test, that calls set_time_limit 10 times:

```
<?php
echo("<html><head><title>set_time test</title></head><body><h1>set_time test</h1>");
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    error_log("Round $i");
    set_time_limit(0); echo("<p>$i</p>");
}
echo("</body></html>");
```

Hangs forever with error:

```
 // Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in .../_set_time.php on line 4
 // Call Stack:
 //   0.0007 231768 1. {main}() .../_set_time.php:0
 //   0.0007 232000 2. set_time_limit() .../_set_time.php:4
```

30 seconds is the value of `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`. If I raise it to 3000, the scripts just keeps spinning. I have AllowOverrideAll for the document root in apache's config (assuming it matters - it shouldn't, but still)

A similar machine (same OS & SW versions, config very close) runs the script flawlessly each time. Log files show nothing. Google searches are mostly silently or irrelevant. Seems some weird system/configuration quirk.

Ideas?

> OS: CentOS 6.9
>   apache 2.2.15
>   php 5.6 (webtatic RPM:php56w-5.6.30-1.w6.x86_64)

**Edit:** Submitted to the xdebug project as bug: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1457

Comment: What's the error that's thrown? And this looks like your code is going into an infinite loop...

Comment: no need to call set_time_limit(0); onto the for loop. just set it only once as first line of ur script. it will set your script time limit to infinite.

Comment: The error (as showed in the post) is execution time exceeded- but as mentioned, raising execution time in php.ini just makes it hang forever, on the first call to set_time_limit, mostly.  The loop runs (when it does at all) 10 times ($i <10). I do not need to call set_time_limit in a loop, the code is just a POC to trigger a behaviour I have observed in a moodle installation - which hangs on just such a  call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the culprit is the xdebug extension (installed on one machine but not on the other). By removing it (php56w-pecl-xdebug-2.5.3-1.w6.x86_64) the unwanted behavior disappears. Bit tricky, took more than 2 days to pinpoint, between narrowing it to set_time_limit and finding the responsible extension.